# How to use a custom layout for a button in a tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-custom-view

I have made a custom layout that I want to use as button (like a tab).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/Blue_Background">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/car_icon"
        android:gravity="right"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Car Model"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result: [image: Custom button layout]

I want to use this layout in a Horizontal Scrollview, as a tab, adding new customs buttons programatically. How can I do this?

[image: Custom button layout] [image: Custom button layout] [image: Custom button layout]

I don't know If I have explain me well. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way and let me know still getting any stuff
1. you have already declare custom xml for your cutom button
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/Blue_Background">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/car_icon"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Car Model"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
2. create custom properties for your custom button "attrs.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
        <attr name="caption" format="string" />
        <attr name="left_drawable" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
3. create custom class for your custom button
public class CustomButton extends LinearLayout {

    private LinearLayout base;
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView text;

    private String buttonCaption;
    private int buttonImage;

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context,attrs);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context,attrs);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context,null);
    }

    private void init(Context mContext,AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_button, null);


        base = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.base);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        if(attributeSet!=null){
            String namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" + getContext().getPackageName();
            buttonCaption = attributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, "caption");
            buttonImage = attributeSet.getAttributeIntValue(namespace, "left_drawable", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        addView(v, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setActionListener();
    }

    private void setActionListener() {

       base.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setButtonCaption (String caption){
        buttonCaption = caption;
    }
    public void setButtonLeftDrawable(int drawable){
        buttonImage = drawable;
    }

    public String getButtonCaption (){
        return text.getText().toString();
    }
    public int getButtonLeftDrawable(){
        return buttonImage;
    }

    private void updateView(){
        image.setImageResource(buttonImage);
        text.setText(buttonCaption);
    }
}
4. use this custom button in xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.Demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.example.Demo.CustomButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:caption="button"
       app:left_drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
5. also change custom button properties at run time like normal button.
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomButton customButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        customButton = (CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.mtCustomButton);

        customButton.setButtonCaption("myCustomButton");
        customButton.setButtonLeftDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use your layout in a single `Textview` tag, using background (purple), and the [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) property.

Then, once done, you should look to [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), because then, what you will need is to apply the same style to all your textviews.

Comment: How can I define size, drawableLeft property and background programmatically? Sorry, but I am starting with android. And Thank you.

Comment: I can define a new textviews like the next way?

ViewGroup scrollview = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scroll_of_applies);

TextView newtab = new TextView(this);
            newtab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue_Background));
newtab.setText(appl.getName());
newtab.setTextSize(18);
newtab.setHeight(200);
newtab.setWidth(48);
newtab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.coche_blanco, 0, 0, 0);
newtab.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 48));
scrollview.addView(newtab);

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, when you say you want to use the custom layout as 'tabs', you mean you want to create a tab-based view navigation with scrollable tabs.
If yes, then have a look at the following training topic on the android developers website that shows how to create tab based swipe views :

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

For customizing the tabs, you can look at [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) and [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html), as those are the view groups that contain the tabs.

Comment: No, I don't want a tab, only a row with textviews, buttons or imageviews. Thank you for your effort.